# AWS API to get free tier amount for each service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

Is there an AWS API to get free tier amount for each service?

I'm using the AWS Cost Explorer API to get usage of each AWS service.

GetCostAndUsage API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html

But this API return all usage, including free tier amount.

I need to subtract the free tier amount, but didn't find any filter or another API that return this information.

Is there an API for that?

What I need is basically the free tier information shown in this page:
https://aws.amazon.com/free

But provided in an API, with JSON format.

My current Cost Explorer API request is like that:

```
{
    "TimePeriod": {
        "Start": startDate,
        "End": endDate
    },
    "Granularity": "MONTHLY",
    "GroupBy":[
        {
            "Type":"DIMENSION",
            "Key":"SERVICE"
        },
        {
            "Type":"DIMENSION",
            "Key":"USAGE_TYPE"
        }
    ],
    "Metrics": ["UsageQuantity"]
}
```

Comment: Yes, AWS recently announced a new API that you can check your usage of the AWS Free Tier. [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/check-your-aws-free-tier-usage-programmatically-with-a-new-api/](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/check-your-aws-free-tier-usage-programmatically-with-a-new-api/)